# How smooth is Black-Scholes?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

For each variable $(S,T,K,r,q,\sigma)$ in the Black-Scholes formula, how many times can you take a partial derivative?

Adjacently, is the nth order greek for some variable a constant?

Thanks

Comment: A composition of $C^\infty$ functions (Black Scholes formula) is also $C^\infty$. Thus, you can compute arbitrarily many partial derivatives.

Comment: @Kevin nice. I am wondering wether we should see some derivatives go to zero with $N\to \infty$, but I do not think that answer would ‘help’ OP.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I was only responding to the first of the two questions. Because higher order Greeks quickly turn into highly nonlinear equations, including special functions whose derivatives don’t vanish, I have no reason to believe that the Black Scholes Greeks ever equal zero (they however surely reduce in magnitude though like delta-gamma-speed). I’d be more inclined to believe that cross partial derivatives may eventually equal zero. What do you think?

Comment: @Kevin sorry, I was referring to my answer - your’s is correct, of course! Thinking out loud: any nth derivative will probably always consist of scaled sums of normal densities. For example the  nth derivative with respect to the underlying $S$ will behave something like $S^{-N+1}$ times the normal density $n(d_1)$ which is bounded from above and should hence decay to zero, but that’s of course not a ‘constant’ I admit. NB:all this are back-of-the-envelope kind of guesstimates, I could be totally wrong here.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I'd fully follow your intuition. My gut feeling, too, would be that the derivatives tend to zero (have no real impact on pricing), but never quite reach zero directly. You have this nice motivation for $\frac{\partial^N}{\partial S^N}$ and I'd guess it would be similar for other variables or cross derivatives

Comment: Beware of numerical issues if you calculate numerical derivatives though. Even if the theoretical model is in itself smooth, the smoothness of numerical derivatives depend a lot of the implementation,